# Is it acceptable to put code to load an image into an Image control in the code behind file of a View in WPF MVVM?

Tags: wpf, mvvm, standards

I am unclear about which conventions I should follow in regards to the code behind file of a View in WPF MVVM.

In my specific scenario, I want to know whether it is considered good practice to place code in the code behind, linked to the click event of a button on my view, to locate an image from the hard drive and load this into an Image control on the View. The code would look something like this:

```
var ofd = new OpenFileDialog { Filter = "Bitmap Files(*.bmp)|*.bmp" };

ofd.ShowDialog();

if (ofd.FileName != null)
{
    var image = BitmapFactory.ConvertToPbgra32Format(new WriteableBitmap(new BitmapImage(new Uri(ofd.FileName, UriKind.Absolute))));

    MyImageControl.Width = image.Width;
    MyImageControl.Height = image.Height;

    MyImageControl.Source = image;
}
```

Is this too much logic for the code-behind of a view? If so should I place this in the ViewModel or just in a different class and call the method from the View?

Also, on a broader scale, it would be great if somebody could provide a link to some definitive guidelines regarding what is generally considered acceptable to put in the code-behind of a view, and what is not.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, it's important to remember that MVVM is, like you said, a set of *guidelines* not rules. And sometimes it can get a little sketchy what should be where...

That said, in your example you have quite a lot of *logic* which is **not** UI-Specific logic.

Loading the picture from the hard drive should definitely  be done in the ViewModel. 
The image should then be set on a Property in the ViewModel. Then, the Image control in the View should *bind* the `ImageSource` to said property.

About the Dialog (e.g. the OpenFileDialog) - There are 3 valid (IMHO) ways this can be done.

**First** is to create a 'FileChoosingService' which is called by the ViewModel and, in turn, it raises the OpenFileDialog and returns the filename.

**Second** option is to open the Dialog from the View, and set the result into a property in the ViewModel. The viewmodel will see that the property has changed and in turn load the image from the HardDrive.

**Third** option is just like the second, only instead of setting the property, have the view invoke a `LoadImageCommand` in the ViewModel and pass as a `CommandParameter` the filename.

Comment: OK thanks, that makes sense. In my ViewModel, should I then implement INotifyPropertyChanged, and put logic in my code-behind to update the image on property changed?

Comment: You'll need INotifyPropertyChanged to get notified when the `MyImage` property changes... But you don't need logic in your code-behind to update the image. Just make sure you set your view's `DataContext` to the ViewModel and bind the Image's source to the `MyImage` property in the ViewModel

Answer (score 1):

The general best practice is to avoid any code behind *where possible*. It sounds like in this case you can avoid it, and that this isn't just a concern of the view. In other words it's some logic that could be applied to different views over the same view model.

Also as the code is in the code behind, it is harder to test. You might want to test that if the user selects an invalid image file, that an error is logged etc. This is fair easier when the logic is in the view model.

There also doesn't seem a technical reason why this wouldn't be put in the view model anyway.

To answer your other question, you should have a public property in your view model which is the current image, and you should use data binding in the view to bind that image property to the source of your `Image` control.

You should also seriously consider using an MVVM framework. They will provide a base view model type that already implements `INotifyPropertyChanged`.